# How is this animated .png possible?

Tags: animation, graphics, png, gif, apng

While learning how to edit Firefox themes, I came across this animated .png (not apng) that I do not understand.  I assumed it was a gif at first just given the pixel art style.

.png in question:

[image: PNG] (reuploaded to a site of mine)

The .png is part of this theme:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/black-rain-remasterd-dark-mode/

and this is the url for the image in question when I inspect the theme:

- moz-extension://0c38fbf3-159e-4a75-8215-b2e881443fc9/images/0.png

Tried to open in Photoshop and a visual studio code, opens like any other still .png would and not like say a .gif that would show me the frames.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid, animated PNG.

You can check it with `pngcheck` as follows:

```
pngcheck -v 0.png

File: 0.png (991263 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    640 x 65 image, 8-bit palette, interlaced
  chunk PLTE at offset 0x00025, length 768: 256 palette entries
  chunk tRNS at offset 0x00331, length 256: 256 transparency entries
  chunk pHYs at offset 0x0043d, length 9: 3779x3779 pixels/meter (96 dpi)
  chunk acTL at offset 0x00452, length 8
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk fcTL at offset 0x00466, length 26
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x0048c, length 21371
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression
    rows per pass: 9, 9, 8, 17, 16, 33, 32
  chunk fcTL at offset 0x05813, length 26
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk fdAT at offset 0x05839, length 21371
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  ...
  ...
  ...
  chunk fcTL at offset 0xecc09, length 26
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk fdAT at offset 0xecc2f, length 21468
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk IEND at offset 0xf2017, length 0
No errors detected in 0.png (100 chunks, -2282.8% compression).
```

Or check with:

```
magick identify -verbose 0.png
```

---

You will see it contains both `fcTL` *"Frame Control Chunk"* and `acTL` *"Animation Control Chunk"*. See [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification#.60acTL.60:_The_Animation_Control_Chunk).

Comment: So its not a PNG but different fileformat with somewhat PNG backwards compatibility. Is the format official or just a hack?

Comment: Interesting, how would one go about making his own?

Comment: @RickFeit You just follow original fileformat and inject your chunks if original specs allows it ... some fileformats have reserved chunk types for future expansions ... if none present its possible inject chunks that are not recognized and skipped but that depends on image loader implementations and might bring problems in 3th party apps .... if no other possibility you just append your stuff at the end of image similarly how EXIF works for non chunkable image fileformats but again this might bring problems ... even antivirus might suspect it

Comment: @Spektre AFAIK it is a legitimate, compliant (A)PNG.